# Printer is connected and online, but can't print

Tags: windows, windows-vista, network-printer

I'm on a Toshiba Satellite Laptop with a Brother printer, I have successfully connected the two and the printer shows up online in my "printers" selection page. My whole family also uses the printer and theirs all print perfectly fine (my mom has a Toshiba too and my dad has an HP), however mine always displays error.

Is there someway to fix this?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Can you tell us how you connect?  Printer model? And as noted, what error

Comment: HL-2270DW model and it just has error printing i'm not sure what the error is though

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest drivers from the printers website for your OS.

1. Remove the printer software and drivers
2. Re-install.

Comment: It's all updated but there's still no connection

Comment: Is your user account in the computer admin group?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to stop and start the spooler.

in command prompt. (Net stop spooler) then (net start spooler)  minus the brackets